# Favourite tags colours

Tags: feature-request, tag-watching

I have all my favourite tags:

```
asp javascript asp-classic ajax vb.net vbscript vb6 vb html xhtml css asp.net
```

Some of these are of more interest to me than others, [image] for example I am more interested in Javascript than .net, but don't want to remove .net because if there are no JS questions I'll go for the .net ones.

[image]  But all the questions are shaded the same colour on the front page so it's hard to find the JS ones specifically without some braining.

My suggestion is perhaps to either have levels of priority with each tag that shade darker than tags with a lesser priority.

So if my `JS` tag is highest priority [image] it will shade the background of this darker than `.net` ones, so at a glance I can munch my cornflakes and pick the questions I'm most interested by sight rather than thinking too hard and cornflakes and milk falling out my mouth all over my desk

Maybe have 3 levels, one background is opacity 30%, one is 60% and the other is 100% opaque.

[image]

The benefits of this system would be more targeted expert answers and a better experience for questions answerers

Comment: It's not a bad idea, but I can easily see this turning into a headache-inducing home page.

Comment: If you kept it simple, and an extra option for advanced users, and limited it to 3 levels of transparency for the background I think the homepage would be fine still

Comment: Jeff's not the biggest fan of extra options, so I doubt that will get any traction with him...

Comment: :-(  Maybe it can shade the tags based on the % of questions you asked with that tag?