# Request for feature to disable "Favourite Tags" highlighting

Tags: feature-request, tag-watching

Personally I find the orange-beige highlighting of questions with "Favourite Tags" on SO really distracting. I might just delete my "Favourite Tags" to get around this, but I find it helpful to store a list of tags that I find particularly useful.  So, I suggest to make it possible to disable the highlighting that goes along with "Favourite Tags".

[Here is a related feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75219/favourite-tags-colours), but that person was asking for significantly more than what I've mentioned here.

Comment: If you go into the actual tag those posts won't be highlighted anymore... Only questions with **other** favorite tags...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could remove all your favourite tags, and instead create a [filter for them](https://stackexchange.com/filters). No highlighting when browsing Stack Overflow, but you'd still have them stored somewhere. And you can create as many filtered lists as you want, using tags from all Stack Exchange sites.

If that doesn't work for you, you should consider writing a simple [user script](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/stack-apps-and-scripts/) to disable highlighting, or even change the background color to something more to your liking.